# Can not get music player app to work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I am working on my project for school.

Everything runs fine, but the only problem is when I click on a song, the song does not play.

Please help with a detailed explanation, so I can finish the app.

I think the problem could be a warning I am getting, but I am not sure.

Here is the warning:

file:///Volumes/SAMAD%20COHEN/iOS/FinalProjectMusicPlayer/FinalProjectMusicPlayer/FirstViewController.swift: warning: Missing file: /Volumes/SAMAD COHEN/iOS/FinalProjectMusicPlayer/FinalProjectMusicPlayer/FirstViewController.swift is missing from working copy

Here is the code:

```
 import UIKit
 import AVFoundation

 var songs:[String] = []
 var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var myTabelView: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return songs.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = songs[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{

    do
    {
        if let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs[indexPath.row], ofType: ".mp3") {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath) as URL)
            audioPlayer.play()

        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}



override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    gettingSongName()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func gettingSongName()  // Get the names of all the songs
{
     let folderUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.resourcePath!)

    do
    {
        let songPath = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles) // Axcess all of the song files

        for song in songPath
        {
            var mySong = song.absoluteString


            if mySong.contains(".mp3")
            {
                let findString = mySong.components(separatedBy: "/")
                mySong = (findString[findString.count-1])
                mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: " ")
                mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: ".mp3", with: " ")
                songs.append(mySong)

            }
        }

        myTabelView.reloadData()
    }
    catch
    {

    }

}


}
```

Comment: did you add breakpoints and check whether you are getting the file you are trying to play?

Comment: @Shabir Jan No I didn't, how would I do that?

Comment: You just need to add break point in didselectRow Method and check the whether the codes follow the catch block or not